# Isomorphic flux render on server after all requests

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am having trouble figuring out the best way for the serve to render my react components only after the http requests have been resolved.

For example:

component A <- component B <- component C (C triggers an action which makes a call to the API and returns data to render, in the mean time just renders 'loading').

When inspecting my source code, I only see 'loading' and would like, for SEO purposes, the server to wait till component C's call has resolved and rendered.

In theory, that sounds easy because the server should call that action itself and wait till the action is finished then call `react.renderToString()`, like this:

```
server.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    showMessages({}, function showMessagesCallback() { //add a callback
        var html = React.renderToString(ChatComponent());
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

But what if multiple components make action calls and I need to wait for multiple actions to solve and then call `renderToString`

Instead, the requests are picked up on the client side. My server file:

```
/**
 * This leverages Express to create and run the http server.
 * A Fluxible context is created and executes the navigateAction
 * based on the URL. Once completed, the store state is dehydrated
 * and the application is rendered via React.
 */

import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import {navigateAction} from 'fluxible-router';
import debugLib from 'debug';
import React from 'react';
import app from './app';
import HtmlComponent from 'components/Html';
const htmlComponent = React.createFactory(HtmlComponent);

const debug = debugLib('quran-com');

const server = express();
server.set('state namespace', 'App');
server.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')));
server.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/images')));
server.use('/fonts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/styles/fonts')));

server.use((req, res, next) => {
    let context = app.createContext();

    debug('Executing navigate action');
    context.getActionContext().executeAction(navigateAction, {
        url: req.url
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.status && err.status === 404) {
                next();
            } else {
                next(err);
            }
            return;
        }

        debug('Exposing context state');
        const exposed = 'window.App=' + serialize(app.dehydrate(context)) + ';';

        debug('Rendering Application component into html');
        const html = React.renderToStaticMarkup(htmlComponent({
            context: context.getComponentContext(),
            state: exposed,
            markup: React.renderToString(context.createElement())
        }));

        debug('Sending markup');
        res.type('html');
        res.write('<!DOCTYPE html>' + html);
        res.end();
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

export default server;
```

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve. What data should be rendered? Where is it fetched?

Comment: What does "render server-side only when all http requests have returned." mean? What's this set of HTTP requests are you referring to? And what do you mean with returned? Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I updated the question to better explain

Comment: You'll need to use a technique to delay the final render until all of the components have fetched their data or centralize the data request, and again, wait.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, okay sounds good - how to do that? :)

Comment: I consider a good answer to that much too long for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink architecture of your app. Components should not be getting data themselves, you are better of when something gives data to them.

My suggestion would be to do it in the navigate action, so that it becomes entry point into any view. Then here you can resolve all data needed and feed stores with that data, once resolved call the callback. E.g.:

```
module.exports = {

    navigateAction: function (context, state, done) {
        var completeNavigation = function () {
            context.dispatch('NAVIGATE_DONE');
            done()
        }

        var route = _.last(state.routes);

        debug('navigate to: ' + route.name);

        switch (route.name) {
            case 'products':
                context.executeAction(productActions.loadProducts, null, completeNavigation);
                break;
            default:
                completeNavigation();
                break;
        }

    }

};
```

In this sample I'm using `react-router`.

Comment: I am with you on the stores keeping the data and pushing it to the components. +1 on that. I do like your approach of having some action, which the server calls, as the first step which waits for everything else to resolve. Can I not simply for a `.waitFor` on all the stores?